# prepared statements execute multiple queries at once

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been trying this for hours and still no luck. Simply I am deleting rows from two tables using checkboxes. Let's assume I have checked two results and hit delete, then those two rows should be deleted from both tables.

In the below code the first query deletes two rows but the second one only deletes one row. If I just run each query separately then they both delete two rows? I have tried many times but I am not able to achieve what I wanted.

Can someone pleaseeee tell me why each query is failing to delete two rows? or is there a better way to do this? some kind of alternative?

```
  $stmt1  = $mydb->prepare("DELETE from laptop where username = ? and id = ?");
echo $mydb->error;
foreach  ($_POST['id'] as $id)
{
$stmt1->bind_param('ss', $username->username, $pdata);
$stmt1->execute();
}

$stmt2  = $mydb->prepare("DELETE from search where username = ? and id = ?");
echo $mydb->error;
foreach  ($_POST['id'] as $id)
{
$stmt2->bind_param('ss', $username->username, $id);
$stmt2->execute();
}
```

Comment: Using `$_POST[]` directly in SQL queries will **DEFINITELY** lead to SQL Injections (http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: @haywire that isn't even a case here, I am stuck with a bigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine into one query?

```
$stmt1  = $mydb->prepare("DELETE from laptop, search where username = ? and id = ?");
```

Comment: the `id` should be equal to the value of `$pdata` for the first query and `$id` for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above the first query is looping over $_POST['id'], but it's always using the same value $pdata as the param for id=?.

If that query is deleting multiple rows, then you've got rows with duplicate username/id in that table. You should remove the loop, as you are doing extra work running the same delete query multiple times.

You mentioned that the first query was working and the second one wasn't though.

If that's the case, could you echo out the value of $id within your loop and verify that it is looping twice and the values are what you're expecting?